# Does filtering a PHP array cause numbers to skip?

Tags: php

I have code that starts with a list of articles.  I only want to keep those that have a thumbnail attached, so I wrote the function `findThumb` to try and fetch the image, or return false if it trips an error.  Everything works, but when the output is displayed in a numbered list, the counting completely skips numbers 8 & 9 (i.e., 5, 6, 7, 10).  I can't figure out why--by the time it's counting, it's already using the filtered list.  I'm newish to PHP so I'm wondering if this is some weird language quirk I don't know about.

```
<?php

$popularArticles = $curatedArticles->fetchGroup('most-popular');
$findThumb = function ($article) {
    try{
        return $article->original->getImageUrl('tiny');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
};

$popularArticlesWithImages = array_filter($popularArticles, $findThumb);

<section>
<?
    $totalArticles = 10;
    foreach($popularArticlesWithImages as $i => $popularArticle):
        if ($i >= $totalArticles){ break; }
?>
    <dl>
        <dt><?= $i + 1 ?></dt>
        <dd class="most-popular-title"><?= $popularArticle->title ?></dd>
        <? endforeach ?>
    </dl>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

> Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array. **Array keys are preserved.**

(my emphasis)

If you don't want to preserve keys, then simply run [array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) against the filtered array

```
$popularArticlesWithImages = array_values(array_filter($popularArticles, $findThumb));
```

Comment: Thanks--I come from Python and it works differently there.  I read that part of the docs but I interpreted it wrong.